# Default value for null fields using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I would like to set default values for some fields on my model, so if during deserialization my json has missing fields, those default values are used.
What I would like to understand which is the best practice to do this, and why.
I should add the control of null in the setters of my model, I should use the try catch to find any cases, I should extend and modify typeAdapter (this solution seems very verbose to me, let me know if I'm wrong) or there is a even better solution?

Comment: what about lazy loading? also you can use custom deserializer, but I think for your case, lazy loading is the best and simple way.

Comment: I personally do not know what the best solution is, however an easy to implement solution is to mark a field as private and nullable, and add a getter which does a null check which will return a non-nullable value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those won't be available be in JSON data at all, then just initiate the variables.

```
private int id = -1;
private String name = "User not available";
```

If there is a probability that you might get `null` values, then check for it in getters

```
private String DEFAULT_NAME = "User not available";

private String name;

public String getName(){
  if(null == name) return DEFAULT_NAME;
  return name; 
}
```